22.04.4 will not power off
When I try to power off (e.g., using "Power Off" from the Gnome menu, or using sudo shutdown now) I just get a black screen with a white underscore, but the machine still runs unless I hard power off.
How can I approach understanding and correcting this behavior?

Try and hit esc while this is happening, you may be able to see stop jobs running, which may give a good hint about what's going on and possibly hanging. Although some stop jobs IME are just in absolutely no hurry and definetly take their own time.

Does this answer your question? How to debug computer not shutting down issue on 21.04?
